# Load image in bitmap from Uri in android Q

Tags: java, android

There are similar questions but with deprecated code for android Q...

I am taking and storing photos in a custom folder, for android Q I use:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, namePhoto() + ".jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/Folder");
            imagenUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            MyPreferences.setPhotoUri(imagenUri.toString(), getContext());
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imagenUri);
        }
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 199);
    }
```

setPhotoUri stores this **content://media/external/images/media/201**,
I use the uri to show the photo:

```
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(MyPreferences.getPhotoUri(getContext())));
```

the problem is that I need to show a lot of photos and I understand that `setImageURI` can consume a lot of memory and I can't load the image with Bitmap, I only want to show thumbnails, everything I find on the internet is deprected, how can i do it in Android Q?

Comment: Pass the `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso.

Comment: thanks for answering, I have read your blog [Uri Access Lifetime: Still Shorter Than You Might Think](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html), I understand that in my case I do not have the risk that my Uri expires, do I?

Comment: You should be OK from that standpoint.